# При попытке открыть /wp-admin неавторизованным пользователем выдает ли wordpress 401 ошибку?

Tags: wordpress

Попробовал отследить это через консоль в браузере, но тишина - просто молча выкидывает на страницу авторизации.

Comment: Быть может, 403?

Comment: @Vyacheslav Potseluyko Нет, меня интересует именно Not Authorized, а не Forbidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дефолтно нет. С чего бы?
Он выдаёт 302 на страницу для авторизации.